# Removing cloned jQuery UI button will remove base button's style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've set up this Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/MNpRh/4/

```
$("#removebtn").button();
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
$("#clone").click(function(){
   $("#removebtn").parents(".group").clone(true).appendTo("#content");
});
```

Hit Clone a couple times then remove any button. The button style will be removed and not cloned again.

It's based on jQuery UI 1.8. It works in 1.10, but I'm not able to upgrade jQuery UI.

How would you solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the `true` boolean. http://jsfiddle.net/MNpRh/3/ As you are delegating the event you don't need to pass `true` and IDs(_identifires_) must be unique.

Comment: if you remove `true`, e.g. the hover effect will not work on cloned items

Comment: This is where event delegation can be used instead of copying handlers.

Comment: I have modified the code a little bit to prevent ID cloning.

Comment: Can you please provide an example and working code of event delegation?

Comment: You have already used event delegation `$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){`.

Comment: Oh that is what you meant. If you can, please provide me a working example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U2aYF/

Answer (score 1):

To keep hover effect please see modified solution with added pattern div which is hidden by CSS http://jsfiddle.net/MNpRh/8/

Addition to HTML:

```
<div class="group" id="pattern">
     <button class="remove">Remove me</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pattern { display:none;}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#removebtn").button();
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
$("#clone").click(function(){
  $('#pattern').clone().appendTo("#content").removeAttr('id').find('button').button();
});
```

Comment: As you can see, if you remove `true`, the hover effect will not work on cloned items.